# Как дождаться выполнения метода

Tags: android, многопоточность, facebook-api

У меня есть метод

```
public String getProfileUrl() {
        for (UserInfo profile : sCurrentUser.getProviderData()) {
            String provider = profile.getProviderId();

            if (provider.equals("facebook.com")) {
                getFacebookAvatarPhoto();
            } else {
                mProfileUrl = sCurrentUser.getPhotoUrl().toString();
            }
        }
        return mProfileUrl;
    }
```

метод getFacebookAvatarPhoto выполняется в отдельном потоке. Как мне дождаться выполнения этого метода и только потом вернуть значение?

```
 private void getFacebookAvatarPhoto() {
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("fields", "id,email,gender,cover,picture.type(large)");
            new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "me", params, HttpMethod.GET,
                    response -> {
                        if (response != null) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject();
                                if (data.has("picture")) {
                                    mProfileUrl = data.getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data").getString("url");
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }).executeAsync();

        }
```

Comment: Что планируете в основном потоке и Activity , пока метод работает ?

Comment: Метод планируется использоваться в двух местах в данный момент. Первый случай это просто активити с userInfo где будут отображаться данные пользователя, а второй случай это отправка объекта на сервер с этим фото, здесь по идее должно просто закроется текущее активити и откроется активити со списком.

Comment: Можно сделать ProgressBar для вида и с помощью Handler или , если у вас Service - Boardcast'a передать сообщение по истечении метода в главный поток

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не должны заставлять работать асинхронные методы синхронно в главном потоке. Если вы так сделаете - приложение зависнет и система предложит прибить процесс по истечении 5с.

При работе с асинхронными запросами, результаты коих требуются на главном потоке, т.е. для отображения в интерфейсе, с ними надо работать асинхронно.

1. Перед стартом запроса показать юзеру прогресс на экране
2. После получения данных скрыть прогресс и отобразить данные.
3. В случае ошибки - скрыть прогресс и показать кнопку для повторной отправки запроса.

Можно использовать rxJava для преобразования асинхронных вызовов с колбэками в источники `rxJava`. Как-то так:

```
Single<String> profileUrlSingle = Single<String>.create( subscriber -> {
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("fields", "id,email,gender,cover,picture.type(large)");
    new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "me", params, HttpMethod.GET,
            response -> {
                if (response != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject();
                        if (data.has("picture")) {
                            String profileUrl = data.getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data").getString("url");
                            subscriber.onSuccess(profileUrl);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        subscriber.onError(e);
                    }
                } else {
                   subscriber.onError(new NullPointerException());
                }
            }).executeAsync();
});
```

И теперь можно на это подписаться (примерный код, не помню сигнатур методов):

```
profileUrlSingle
    .subscribeOn(Schedullers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedullers.mainThread())
    .doOnSubscribe(() -> showProgress(true))
    .doOnEvent(url, error-> showProgress(false))
    .subscribe(
        url -> doSmthWithUrl(),
        error -> handleError()
    )
```

Comment: Я и не хочу его заставить работать синхронно в UI потоке. Просто получается я вызываю метод и мне нужно получить с него значение, и только после получения значения обновлять интерфейс. Я просто не понимаю как мне обработать метод onComplete в методе получения данных с Фейсбука. Ну я конечно могу вызвать в onComplete метод updateUi. Но мне кажется это не очень красивым решением.

Comment: Вы можете сделать так, как хотите и это будет работать, но в очень ограниченном количестве случаев и это будет предельно неправильно. Правильный способ - как раз тот, что вам не нравится. Т.е. надо в onComplete  вызвать updateUi. Это правильный способ. Да, это выглядит не слишком красиво и понятно и эту проблему обычно решают с помощью специальных либ типа `rxJava`. Там получится ещё менее понятно на первый взгляд и вообще сложно, но в итоге всё будет выглядеть разумно и удобно. Но на данный момент не советую пытаться в неё вникать - очень сложно, правда)

Comment: С RX я уже неоднократно работал. Но почему-то не могу сообразить как правильно переписать это Фейсбук метод в RX. Если подскажете буду благодарен. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Добавил код для rxJava